# "ORA-01438: value larger than specified precision allowed for this column" when inserting 3

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm running into that error when trying to insert any number except 0 into a field with format NUMBER (2,2).

```
UPDATE
    PROG_OWN.PROG_TPORCENTAJE_MERMA
SET
    PCT_MERMA = 3
WHERE
    IDN_PORCENTAJE_MERMA = 1
```

[Error Code: 1438, SQL State: 22003]  ORA-01438: value larger than specified precision allowed for this column

```
COLUMN_NAME DATA_TYPE   TYPE_NAME   COLUMN_SIZE   BUFFER_LENGTH   DECIMAL_DIGITS
PCT_MERMA   3           NUMBER      2             0               2
```

It also happens if I try with decimal numbers.

Any idea why?

Comment: If you're trying to restrict the values to a range or specific integers, you might be better off with a [check constraint](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E14072_01/server.112/e10592/clauses002.htm#SQLRF52204).

Answer (score 42, accepted):

You can't update with a number greater than 1 for datatype `number(2,2)` is because, the first parameter is the total number of digits in the number and the second one (.i.e 2 here) is the number of digits in decimal part. I guess you can insert or update data `< 1`. i.e. 0.12, 0.95 etc.

Please check NUMBER DATATYPE in [NUMBER Datatype](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28318/datatype.htm#i22289).

Answer (score 27):

`NUMBER (precision, scale)` means `precision` number of total digits, of which `scale` digits are right of the decimal point.

`NUMBER(2,2)` in other words means a number with 2 digits, both of which are decimals. You may mean to use `NUMBER(4,2)` to get 4 digits, of which 2 are decimals. Currently you can just insert values with a zero integer part.

[More info at the Oracle docs](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14220/datatype.htm#i16209).