# Why am I getting "value larger than specified precision allowed for this column"?

Tags: oracle, ora-01438

The following SQL produces this error when tried on [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com) for an Oracle database.

> ORA-01438: value larger than specified precision allowed for this column

```
CREATE TABLE fruit
(
  cost NUMBER(4,2) NOT NULL
);
INSERT INTO fruit VALUES ('400.00');
```

Isn't inserting 400.00 allowed, considering that 
[according to the Oracle documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28318/datatype.htm#CNCPT1832), that 400.00 is less than 4 digits before the decimal point and two digits after it?

Comment: Not an exact duplicate maybe, but [the answers to this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14357816/266304) might explain it. Precision of 4 does not mean four digits before the decimal, unless scale is zero.