# ORA-01438: value larger than specified precision allowed for this column ORA-06512: at line 4

Tags: c#, oracle, datatable

From C#code when i am trying to save the data using datatable, i get the above error.

> Exception :ORA-01438: value larger than specified precision allowed for this column  ORA-06512: at line 4

But when i take the 4th row value and insert into DB manually, it gets inserted with out any error.

My code, where i receive exception :

```
 adapter.SelectCommand = new OracleCommand(sqlSelect, connection, transaction);

                adapter.InsertCommand = insertCommand;
                adapter.InsertCommand.Connection = connection;
                adapter.InsertCommand.Transaction = transaction;

                adapter.UpdateCommand = updateCommand;
                adapter.UpdateCommand.Connection = connection;
                adapter.UpdateCommand.Transaction = transaction;

                adapter.DeleteCommand = deleteCommand;
                adapter.DeleteCommand.Connection = connection;
                adapter.DeleteCommand.Transaction = transaction;

                if (oracleRowUpdatingEventHandler != null)
                    adapter.RowUpdating += oracleRowUpdatingEventHandler;

                adapter.Update(dataTable);
```

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["ORA-01438: value larger than specified precision allowed for this column" when inserting 3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14357816/ora-01438-value-larger-than-specified-precision-allowed-for-this-column-when)

Comment: No, i have checked that scenario and i have (5,2) and the value is well in that.

Comment: Can you temporarily change the column to just `number` (instead of `number(5, 2)` and retry the insert; that way, you should be able to see the value that gets inserted, and then you can see if it's what you were expecting it to be.